# Convert the map key and value pair as two fields in a struct in golang

Tags: json, go, struct, hashmap, unmarshalling

I am trying to convert a map's key value pair into a struct's two fields that I have, but facing some issue while doing it.

```
type A struct{
Name string
Value float64
}

type B struct {
    ListOfMetrics []*A
}

func (n *A) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    type origA struct {
        Metrics     map[string]float64 `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=metric" json:"metrics"`
        ListOfMetrics []*A
    }
    var oN origA
    err := unmarshal(&oN)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var Dp []*A
    for metric, value := range oN.Metrics {
        fmt.Println(metric, value)
        n := A{}
        n.Metric = metric
        n.Value = value
        Dp = append(Dp, &n)

    }
    oN.ListOfMetrics = Dp
    var m *B
    m.ListOfMetrics = oN.ListOfMetrics
    return nil
```

Basically I am trying to get the Metrics field of `map[string]float64` into a struct of Metric name `string` and Metric value `float64`, which needs to be stored as a list of metric name and values. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Your method UnmarshalYAML is defined for A, but A is just a pair.

For me.. make sense put it in B

Also your logic seems complex. You create a local variable with your content and there is no way to recover it from outside (without an extra effort)

I wrote a small example using json as base, can be a starting point

https://go.dev/play/p/13lDeu3BkwQ